# How to execute python script without typing python on the start?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-3.8

I was using Python 3.6 and i could run scripts only by typing "Some Script.py", but after uninstalling 3.6 and installing 3.8, i cannot run scripts that way anymore, it seems python is detected but doesnt work as intended, for example:

if i run "My Script.py", it says `ImportError: No module named <module>`
but if i run `python "My Script.py"` it works perfectly

i tried typing python --version, py --version and all of them returns me 3.8.6 (the version i'm using)

i already set python.exe as default program for .py
also started cmd as admin and typed in `assoc .py=Python.File` and `ftype Python.File=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe "%1" %*`
as the python FAQ says that python association is done by Pyhon.File (idk if that's right)

I also have added `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts` and `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38` to the path

Note: i also searched on alot of stackoverflow and reddit threads but didnt found any fix for me

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.8.6

Comment: Do you have two versions of Python installed? It might be, that you have installed packages for one of the distributions (which is associated with `python`) where the `python.exe` you have set as default for `.py` programs is the other one?

Comment: Furthmore, can you execute a simple "hello world" i.e just running `hello_world.py` with `hello_world.py` only containing the line `print("Hello world")` ?

Comment: yes i can run a simple print @CutePoison

Comment: i'll try removing my 2.7 version

Comment: tysm @CutePoison it was a conflict with my 2.7 version, it's working right now

Comment: Thats good news.